# DocuSign Branding Email Merge Field

Tags: docusignapi

I have a logo (210 x 73 px) which I uploaded to the primary position under Branding -> Resources in the DocuSign Branding page primary logo position at the DocuSign site.

I have included the logo inside the Email Resource file which makes up my email template, said html:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="520" class="fullWidthWithGapMobile">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.example.com/">
                <img src="[[Data:PresetPath]][[BrandString:LogoPath]]" alt="blah blah blah" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Unfortunately the image is not being displayed, but upon inspection with Chrome Developer Tools it appears as though the image path is being set by the merge field [[Data:PresetPath]][[BrandString:LogoPath]] because the html img src is "https://www.docusign.net/Member/Image.aspx?i=logo&l=e0297835-51a2-4148-8d85-b57713876c88".

Furthermore, when I preview the http headers for the image it's getting an HTTP response code of 200. The strange thing is though that when I try to view the response for the image asset inside Developer Tools, there is no response data available.

Additionally, the output of other merge fields appears to be not working, e.g.

```
style="color:[[BrandString:DialogHeaderColor]];"
```

The data for [[BrandString:DialogHeaderColor]] is available in the brand resource file which I have downloaded and checked. A sample extract of the Branding XML is here for your convenience:

```
<Brand>
    <BrandId>a81a087c-4R3d-4d90-9zpf-c8399a555e46</BrandId>
    <BrandName>Brand X</BrandName>
    <CompanyName>Company X</CompanyName>
    <BackgroundColor>#00B0B9</BackgroundColor>
    <BackgroundTextColor>#333333</BackgroundTextColor>
    <DialogHeaderColor>#008C95</DialogHeaderColor>
    ...
```

Any assistance that anybody can provide would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Here's the screen capture of the uploaded logos in the docusign web interface.
[image]

Comment: Regarding the logo in the html table in your email, i just tested this using my own sample email resource file and it worked as expected. Are you sure that you have uploaded an 'email logo' in the resource file? That needed to be uploaded for my test to work.

Comment: Hello Luis. Thanks for trying it out for me. Yes, I have logos uploaded for each of the available logo alternatives. I've updated the initial question to include a screen dump showing the logos.